# Get array element values without square brackets and double quotes

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, indexing

I have a couple of Ruby arrays:

```
array1 = ["a", "b"]
array2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
array3 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
array4 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

I need to return the following strings:

```
#array1
"a"

#array2
"a and b"

#array3
"a, b and c"

#array4
"a, b, c and d"
```

The last element of the array should never be displayed.

I don't know in advance how many elements an array contains or the value of these elements.

To achieve what I need, I came up with the following method:

```
def format_array(array)
  if array.length - 1 == 1
    array[0].to_s
  elsif array.length - 1 == 2
    array[0].to_s + " and " + array[1].to_s
  elsif array.length - 1 > 2
    array.sort.each_with_index do |key, index|
      unless key == "e"
        if index == array.length - 2
          " and " + array[index].to_s
        else
          array[index].to_s + ", "
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This method returns an arrays of values with square brackets and double quotes instead of lean strings. For instance, I get `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]` instead of `"a, b, c and d"` for `array4`.

How can I make this work?

Comment: You do not return any string at the end of the length of the array is more than 2 so the sorted array is returned as is. Remember in ruby the last statement executed in a method is evaluated and returned. So just store your generated string in an object and return it at the end. Also, I do not know why you check with `array.length - 1` , it should be `array.length`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your are correct, in the way I had initially asked the question, it did not make any sense to check with `array.length - 1`: I updated the question to give more context. Basically, it is because I never want to display the last element of the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def join_with_commas_and_and(array)
  if array.length <= 2
    array.join(' and ')
  else
    [array[0..-2].join(', '), array[-1]].join(' and ')
  end
end
```

EDIT: to ignore the last element, add this line as the first line in the function:

```
array = array[0..-2]
```

Comment: Golfed for fun and profit: `array.push(array.pop(2).join ' and ').join ', '`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Amadan. It is actually the right answer to the initial question I had asked. But, both your answer and Mohamed Osama's comment made me realize I had not provided enough context. Please excuse me for this.

Comment: @mwp: Very nice. Although, it's destructive; I've tried to keep the original array intact. Cloning it beforehand is an easy fix though.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easiest to disregard `'and'` until commas are inserted, then replace the last comma with `'and'`:

```
def fmt(arr)
  return arr.first if arr.size == 2
  str = arr[0..-2].join(', ')
  str[str.rindex(',')] = ' and'
  str
end
  # ["a", "b"]: a
  # ["a", "b", "c"]: a and b
  # ["a", "b", "c", "d"]: a, b and c
  # ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]: a, b, c and d
```